# Will a 73 inch long electric bike fit with 28 inch wheels

Tags: commuter, electric-bike

2 Question.

1st.  I am looking into buying a electric bike it is 73 inches from tire to tire will it fit in a muni bike rack

2nd will 28 inch wheels fit on a muni rack

Thank you

Comment: You should call your local bus service to ask. Even if 73" is the measurement end to end (not the wheelbase), that's an unusually long bike. 28" wheels shouldn't be a problem, but again, go direct to the source.

Comment: Indirectly answered by @Adam, but what is a muni bike rack? Presuming you refer to a bus or other public transport rack, you will need to specify the rack make/model, or your location and provider of the service.

Comment: I'm guessing that MUNI is the bus company in San Francisco. 
 https://www.sfmta.com/getting-around/bike/bikes-muni
Might be better to ask MUNI at  https://www.sfmta.com/contact-us

Comment: Thank you, have tried unfortunately I call Santa Cruz metro and they did not know, stated they will get back to me might take two weeks. Contacted to other metro pretty much same response. Thanks for your help

Comment: Put it back on the retailer - "I'll buy this bike if you can prove fits on the bike racks". They can take the bike to the nearest bus depot, see if it fits on a bike rack. Not sure how accommodating the bus company and drivers would be, but if they have to pay a fare and go one block, so be it. The retailer will benefit if they know this answer, and if you are prepared to do the leg work you should be able to sort out an arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the specification sheet for the racks here:

https://www.sportworks.com/assets/files/Model-Overview.pdf

The maximum wheelbase (distance between front and rear dropouts) supported is 44" or 48" depending on which model is installed.  A bike that's 73" end to end probably has a 45-46" wheel base so you may not be compatible with all racks.

Note a beefy e-bike with battery installed could also easily exceed the 55lbs rated weight limit.